# Determining dependent tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I need to know which tables depend on other tables. Is it possible to get the relations?

In SQL Server it's possible to see dependent tables. I hope MySQL can do this too.

If it's in pictorical form then that's even better.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you want the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` command?

If there are foreign keys defined, the above command will show you what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the information_schema, especially to key_column_usage table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/key-column-usage-table.html

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Database Explorer (object dependency tree) - a unique feature in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).
Easily explore object's references and dependants in Database Explorer. Compilation of dependants for debugging is now also available through the object's context menu.

[image: dependency example]

Also, [Database Designer](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-designer.html) can show foreign key relations between tables.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you'd want a [graphical front-end to mysql](http://wb.mysql.com/) since you're so used to SQL Server. if the foreign keys are defined, it will show up as a link between entities when you reverse engineer the database.